# Windows Filesystem Minifilter Drivers: can I monitor and prevent FS operations using them?

Tags: winapi, filesystems, driver, minifilter

I need to:
1. Monitor operations on certain drives/paths
2. Prevent read and/or write operations on certain drives/paths
For example:

```
C://Users
D:
```

Can this be done using `Windows Filesystem Minifilter Drivers` ?

I am mostly interested in step 2. In other words can a minifilter cancel a IRP ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is all possible with a filesystem mini filter driver.

For #1 you don't need a mini filter driver you could use a Win32 API like [ReadDirectoryChangesW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465(VS.85).aspx).

For #2 you can not only do that but you can also modify what gets read/written, even of different size.

You can [get started here](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/filterdrv/default.mspx).

Comment: ty. my reasons for using minifilters for 1. is that ReadDirectoryChangesW reports access operations delayed by 1d (xp) or 1h (vista+)

Answer (score 4):

Raymond Chen, who is a long-time Windows developer, addressed a version of this question on his blog - he would recommend using ACLs for preventing operations rather than trying to get code to run to stop it.  See [his post](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2010/05/14/10009454.aspx) on this for some thoughts...

Comment: [professional sollutions](http://www.pgp.com/products/endpoint/index.html) seem to use divers. also setting ACLs on endpoints programmatically is [hard-ish](http://diaryproducts.net/about/operating_systems/windows/disable_usb_sticks), and setting ACLs on, say, USB Disks conditionally by serial number and other factors seems only doable by drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Detours library](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) to handle this task.